# Angularjs-service data update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

This is  basic question on the angularjs service.

I've created a very simple app which has the following code.

```
var App = angular.module('testApp', ['testService']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
{
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/dataDisplay.html', controller: testCtrl})
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

angular.module('testService', []).
factory('svcTest', function($http){
    var myService = 
        {
            getPeopleInfo: function()
            {
                $http.get('/test/app/data/getData.php').success(function(data) {
                     console.log("Data : " + data.people);
                     return  data.people;
                });
            }
        };
    return myService;
});


function testCtrl($scope, svcTest) {
    $scope.people = svcTest.getPeopleInfo();
}
```

When it does '$http.get', I am actually getting the data (and even the getData.php also returns valid JSON.). However the data never gets updated to the testCtrl. Not sure I am doing some thing very silly, being a newbie to Angularjs.

However if I get rid of the services and add the http.get inside the controller, the data is retrieved and updated to the views.

```
function testCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/test/app/data/getData.php').success(function(data) {
                 $scope.people = data.people;
        });
}
```

What is the fundamental issue with the code that I use with the services?

BTW, my HTML is very simple, which displays these info in a simple table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please rewrite your code to as below,

```
angular.module('testService', []).
factory('svcTest', function($http){
    var myService = 
        {
            getPeopleInfo: function()
            {
                return $http.get('/test/app/data/getData.php')
            }
        };
    return myService;
});

function testCtrl($scope, svcTest) {
    var peoplesPromise = svcTest.getPeopleInfo();
    peoplesPromise.success(function(data){
        $scope.people = data.people
    })

}
```

The `$http` returns a promise object which will have `success` and `error` callbacks to which we can listen.

Getting the promise inside the controller and attaching to the callbacks, gives us the access to scope of the controller (`testCtrl`). Then from inside the callback we are updating the `testCtrl` 's `people` property with the response from the request.

Comment: Thanks for answering my very basic question.